# Write a regular expression that finds strings of the following kind

Tags: javascript, regex

The task itself looks like this:
*Given string 'ave a#b a2b a$b a4b a5b a-b acb'. Write a regular expression that finds strings of the following kind: the letters 'a' and 'b' are at the edges, and there is neither a letter nor a number between them.*

It's just really hard for me to make sense of it. But I was able to write something like:

`'ave a#b a2b a$b a4b a5b a-b acb'.replace(/a\Wb/g, "")`,

but it works by replacing only the values I need to output and leaving `'ave a2b a4b a5b acb'`, but I just need to remove everything except `'a#b a$b a-b'`. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all occurrences of the `\ba[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]b\b` pattern that matches `a` not preceded with any word char, then any char other than whitespace, letters and digits, and then a `b` not followed by a word char, and then  join the output with a space:

```js
console.log(
  'ave a#b a2b a$b a4b a5b a-b acb'.match(/\ba[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]b\b/g).join(" ")
)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/44vR26/1).

Note: if the expected matches occur in between whitespaces or start/end of string, you might need to replace word boundaries with whitespace boundaries, `/(?<!\S)a[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]b(?!\S)/g`.